# Why are there brackets in the class of a td tag in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at some html and I came across this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:540px) {
        td[class="spechide"] {
            display: none !important;
        }
}
```

I was able to understand that the first line which makes the css specific to screen sizes that have a maximum width of 540px, but I googled and couldn't find why you need the `class="MainContainer"` in brackets. In the html, the class is specified as usual: `<td class="spechide"`.

Any help or direction is appreciated. :)

Comment: It's technically correct but it's a stinky code smell. Any non-class/non-id attribute used in a CSS selector is wrapped in brackets. `[name='check']` or `[contenteditable]` or `[type=checkbox]`. Note the quotes are optional for the value. The proper way to write `td[class="spechide"]` is `td.spechide` of course.

Comment: You match against a tags attribute. In this case the tag is `td` and the attribute `class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brackets are [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). So in this case it will apply the CSS if the `class` attribute contains the value `"spechide"`. In your example it would be the same using `td.spechide`, but the difference is that if the class contains more than one class (like `<td class="spechide another-class">`), it wont be applied where the `td.spechide` would be:

```css
td[class="spechide"] {
  background-color: red;
}

td.spechide {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Test 1
    </td>
    <td class="spechide">
      Test 2
    </td>
    <td class="spechide another-class">
      Test 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it is entirely possible that someone simply didn't think of using the `.class` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets to target any attribute of a HTML tag. For example... you could have a HTML image tag that looks like this:

```html
<img src="./image.jpg" alt="Image alt" />
```

In CSS you could potentially target this image using the following CSS syntax:

```css
img[alt="Image alt"] {
    display: none;
}
```

---

So in your example, they are oddly targeting the class attribute by using the `[]` square brackets. This is perfectly valid, but when targeting the class attribute, it is much more common to see it written like so:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:540px) {
        td.spechide {
            display: none !important;
        }
}
```

Essentially, this will do the same as you have given in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are usually used as an attribute selector in CSS, it allows you to set style for a html element with it's attribute.

For example:

```css
[data-vegetable="liquid"] { color: blue }
```

```html
<td data-vegetable="liquid">Water</td>
<td data-vegetable="liquid">Wine</td>
<td data-vegetable="no">Meat</td>
```

This example will make elements with `data-vegetable="liquid"` to have a blue coloured text. The context in which you're mentioning square brackets is a non-standard one as there would make more sense to use traditional class selector with dot before class name - `.spechide`.

You can find more on CSS selectors on [MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) as well as on [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors).